# Powershell automate choose file on a website

Tags: javascript, powershell

I am trying to automate uploading of images on a website.  Any idea how I can get the code below working.  I believe the doc.getElementById and getting the files themselves are the issues.  Thanks in advance

```
$url = 'https://cubeupload.com/'

# Create the IE com object 
$ie = new-object -com InternetExplorer.Application 

# Wait for the page to finish loading 
do {sleep 1} until (-not ($ie.Busy)) 
$ie.visible = $true #Uncomment this for debugging 

$link = $doc.getElementById('#pickfiles')
$link.click()


Code Block
<FORM>
<INPUT type=file name=attachment>
</FORM>

<script language=javascript>   
  function window.onload(){   
          document.all.attachment.focus();   
          var WshShell=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")   
          WshShell.sendKeys("D:\MyFile.jpg")
  }   
</script>
```

Comment: You either did not provide a full example, or missed something. At `$link = $doc.getElementById('#pickfiles')` you're referencing var `$doc` that is never populated.

Comment: @restless1987 Hmmm I'll give that a try.  It's either this or use dreaded FTP.  Which fails to update files